# Excel VBA add handler to every checkbox in form

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I have an excel form with a large number of checkboxes that are added at runtime. I would like to add a handler to each one of those checkboxes that will run when the value is changed. I know in other versions of Visual Basic I would use AddHandler, but that doesn't work in Excel VBA.

Following an example, I came up with the following code:

```
'This is in a class module called CheckboxHandler
Public WithEvents cb As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub cb_change()
    MsgBox ("test")
end sub
```

And, in my userform, I have this code:

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
.....'Unrelated code omitted

'Variable Checkboxes
'Add Handler to checkboxes
Dim colCBHandlers As Collection
Set colCBHandlers = New Collection
Dim objHandler As CheckboxHandler

Dim i As Long
Dim chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox
For i = 1 To .count - 1
    Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", "Checkbox" & i)
    chkBox.Caption = .Keys()(i)
    chkBox.VALUE = False
    chkBox.Top = (chkBox.Height + 10) * (i - 1) + 55
    chkBox.Left = 725
    Set objHandler = New CheckboxHandler
    Set objHandler.cb = chkBox
    colCBHandlers.Add objHandler
Next i
End With
```

Comment: Is this in inappropriate question? I'm confused about the downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`colCBHandlers` will go out of scope as soon as the sub which creates the checkboxes exits.

You need to declare that collection as a global (at the module level) so it doesn't get lost once it has been created and populated.

Comment: Thank you! I realized this an came back to update my question, only to find that you already had!