# How do I loop this statement?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Instead of going through each private sub and writing the same code, how can I iterate through each sub and apply the code?

```
Private Sub cmdMenu1_GotFocus()
Me.cmdMenu1.BackColor = RGB(92, 131, 180)
Me.cmdMenu1.ForeColor = RGB(92, 131, 180)
End Sub
Private Sub cmdMenu1_LostFocus()
Me.cmdMenu1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Me.cmdMenu1.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub
Private Sub cmdMenu2_GotFocus()
Me.cmdMenu2.BackColor = RGB(92, 131, 180)
Me.cmdMenu2.ForeColor = RGB(92, 131, 180)
End Sub
Private Sub cmdMenu2_LostFocus()
Me.cmdMenu2.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Me.cmdMenu2.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub
Private Sub cmdMenu3_GotFocus()
Me.cmdMenu3.BackColor = RGB(92, 131, 180)
Me.cmdMenu3.ForeColor = RGB(92, 131, 180)
End Sub
Private Sub cmdMenu3_LostFocus()
Me.cmdMenu3.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Me.cmdMenu3.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub
Private Sub cmdMenu4_GotFocus()
Me.cmdMenu4.BackColor = RGB(92, 131, 180)
Me.cmdMenu4.ForeColor = RGB(92, 131, 180)
End Sub
Private Sub cmdMenu4_LostFocus()
Me.cmdMenu4.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Me.cmdMenu4.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub
Private Sub cmdMenu5_GotFocus()
Me.cmdMenu5.BackColor = RGB(92, 131, 180)
Me.cmdMenu5.ForeColor = RGB(92, 131, 180)
End Sub
Private Sub cmdMenu5_LostFocus()
Me.cmdMenu5.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Me.cmdMenu5.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

etc...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The first step is to create a function (one function, not two) to cover the repetition.

```
Private Sub ChangeMenuColour(Menu as ControlMenu, GotFocus as Boolean)
    If GotFocus then
        ControlMenu.BackColor = RGB(92, 131, 180)
        ControlMenu.ForeColor = RGB(92, 131, 180)
    Else
        ControlMenu.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        ControlMenu.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: declare `Menu` as the right kind of control (type safety), I just used `ControlMenu` as I don't know what sort of control you are using.

Now, for each control, you only have to call the function. For example:

```
Private Sub cmdMenu1_LostFocus()
    ChangeMenuColour Me.cmdMenu1, False
End Sub
```

The advantage of this first step is that if you ever decide to change your colour scheme, you only need to edit a single routine instead of dozens.

For your next step, you can create a custom class that includes a member `WithEvents` which also handles the appropriate event. See [Excel VBA add handler to every checkbox in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788497/excel-vba-add-handler-to-every-checkbox-in-form) for this example. However, the work to achieve this may be more than the simple repetition you have above.

Using the code in the link I had above, tailored to your example:

```
'This is in a class module called MenuHandler
Private WithEvents menu As MSForms.ControlMenu ' substitute with your specific control

Property Set TargetMenu(targetobject as ControlMenu)
    set menu = targetobject
End Property

Private Sub menu_GotFocus()
    ChangeMenuColour True
end sub

Private Sub menu_LosttFocus()
    ChangeMenuColour False
end sub

Private Sub ChangeMenuColour(GotFocus as Boolean) ' Note change in signature, change in context on how this is used
    If GotFocus then
        menu.BackColor = RGB(92, 131, 180)
        menu.ForeColor = RGB(92, 131, 180)
    Else
        menu.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        menu.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Now in your main form, you only need to associate your menus with this handler. You could do this through a collection as per the link above, or (if you have a limited, finite and static number of menus) simply have individual objects (example below). You choose which is most efficient and easiest to maintain in your context.

```
' This is in the user form
' Declare the handler links as module-level, not within any sub or event handler
Private menuHandler1 as new MenuHandler
Private menuHandler2 as new MenuHandler
Private menuHandler3 as new MenuHandler

' The following code would go in the initialise/load event handler
    Set menuHandler1.TargetMenu = cmdMenu1 ' now you don't have to add any other focus handlers for this menu - but you can anyway
    Set menuHandler2.TargetMenu = cmdMenu2
    Set menuHandler3.TargetMenu = cmdMenu3
```

Alternatively

```
' This is in the user form
' Declare the handler links as module-level, not within any sub or event handler
Private menuHandlerCollection as new Collection ' will store the MenuHandlers

' The following code would go in the initialise/load event handler or where you create your menus
    Dim menuHandlerInstance as MenuHandler
    ' Usually some other code here
    ' the following may be in a loop, or you might just have a list of items to add
    ' only a single instance included here as an example
    Set menuHandlerInstance = new MenuHandler
    Set menuHandlerInstance .TargetMenu = cmdMenuX ' now you don't have to add any other focus handlers for this menu
    menuHandlerCollection.Add menuHandlerInstance
```